# How do I Junit test whether a (single) patient has been seen within a year or not

Tags: java, junit

```
//working out what patients have not been seen in 1 year.

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class PatientTest {

public static void main(String[] args){

   Calendar cal1 =Calendar.getInstance(); 
   PatientExtended Patient1 = new PatientExtended("Ian", "04/12/1970", "M", cal1);

   Calendar cal2 =Calendar.getInstance(); 
   cal2.set(2012, 11, 8);
   PatientExtended Patient2 = new PatientExtended("Bob", "13/08/1989", "M", cal2);

   ArrayList<PatientExtended>mylist = new ArrayList <PatientExtended>();

   mylist.add(Patient1);
   mylist.add(Patient2);

   System.out.println(PatientExtended(mylist));

}

public static ArrayList<PatientExtended> PatientExtended(ArrayList<PatientExtended> PatientArrayList){
    Calendar lastYear = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = lastYear.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    year = year -1;
    lastYear.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

    ArrayList<PatientExtended>notSeenAllYear = new ArrayList <PatientExtended>();

    for(int i =1; i<=1; i++){
        System.out.println(i);

    int check = PatientArrayList.get(i).getlastSeen().compareTo(lastYear);

    if (check <= 1){
        notSeenAllYear.add(PatientArrayList.get(i));
    }

    }
        return notSeenAllYear;
    //return new array


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this question from more of a how to use the junit api perspective, rather than trying to work out your test cases, as I believe that's what you're asking. For some basic coverage you could do the following: Note the Kent Beck test naming convention. I should also add I've corrected the case on PatientExtended to patientExtended and made it take the List interface rather than an ArrayList implementation.

```
@Test
public void has_single_patient_been_seen_within_a_year() {
    List<PatientExtended> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new PatientExtended(<your constructor args here>));
    assertEquals(list, patientExtended(list));
};
```